# Parsing JSON to a table using jQuery get()

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to take the following JSON and create an html table.

My code:

```
jQuery.get("/path/to/json?filter=date&pagesize=25&pagestart=1", function(json) {
    console.log(json)
}):
```

gets the following:

```
{
    users:[
        { "username":"Bob",  "datetime":"2015-10-26 01:59:11",  "eventType":"Enroll",  "URL":"http://gogle.com" },
        { "username":"Steve",  "datetime":"2015-10-26 01:49:40",  "eventType":"Enroll",  "URL":"http://bing.com" },
        { "username":"Joe",  "datetime":"2015-10-26 01:48:29",  "eventType":"Enroll",  "URL":"http://facebook.com" }
    ]
 }
```

The problem I am having is looping through the json.

How do I do something like:

```
<tr>
<td> +json.username+ </td>
<td> +json.datetime+ </td>
<td> +json.eventType+ </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The ideal solution for this is HTML templating. Try to get started with http://handlebarsjs.com/. In its current form this is not a proper question for StackOverflow, because you are effectively asking that someone implements your requirements. I suggest you come back when you have a real question (i.e. you're stuck with your own (!) code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the users collection using `$.each` and build the markup for the table row

```
jQuery.get("/path/to/json?filter=date&pagesize=25&pagestart=1", function(json) {

   var trs="";
   $.each(json.users,function(i,item){      

     trs+="<tr><td>"+item.username+"</<td>";
     trs+="<td>"+item.eventType+"</<td></tr>";    

   });
  $("#userTbl").append(trs);

});
```

Assuming you have table like this in your page.

```
<table id="userTbl">
 <tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>Event type</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a working sample. http://jsbin.com/mebogakona/edit?html,js,console,output

Here is a working MVC sample. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VudbyE

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` any reason why?

Comment: can you do `console.log(json)` before  the $.each. My code was assuming that your $.get was getting a a json structure like the one you posted in the question.

Comment: My console log looks just like the json i posted.

Comment: Then it should work fine. See the jsbin sample i posted. make sure you do not have any typos (lowerCase/Uppercase also) in your code

Comment: Mind taking this conv to chat?

Comment: @MatthewWoodard I added a link to a working MVC project . Compare it with your code and see what is missing. make sure you use the correct property names (with proper casing)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers allow you to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which will return an actual javascript object which you can then use some simple loops to print out the proper html.

Comment: I tried that, and am getting the following error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: users must be a string (as in enclosed by quote marks `"`)

Comment: Oh... Sorry. Use @Shyju's answer. I'll leave mine up for future reference for others though.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting JSON with the get method. jquery has a getJSON function like this:

```
var returned_json;
jQuery.getJSON("/path/to/json?filter=date&pagesize=25&pagestart=1", function(json) {
  console.log(json); //sends back the data parsed as a JSON
  returned_json = json;
}
```

then for your table you could loop through each json obj with the .each function.

```
returned_json.each(function(index){
<tr>
    <td> +index.username+ </td>
    <td> +index.datetime+ </td>      
    <td> +index.eventType+ </td>     
</tr>
```

});

im assuming the rows are created as a string and you're going to use .html() function afterwards.

Comment: For some reason when I user getJSON nothing comes back.

Comment: maybe the JSON thats being returned isnt formatted in a way that jquery likes

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that 
`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/z1987/sEwM6/3148/

It's not mine. I just googled it now.